# Pandas DataFrame stored list as string: How to convert back to list

Tags: python, string, list, pandas, dataframe

I have an *n*-by-*m* Pandas DataFrame `df` defined as follows. (I know this is not the best way to do it. It makes sense for what I'm trying to do in my actual code, but that would be TMI for this post so just take my word that this approach works in my particular scenario.)

```
>>> df = DataFrame(columns=['col1'])
>>> df.append(Series([None]), ignore_index=True)
>>> df
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [col1]
Index: []
```

I stored lists in the cells of this DataFrame as follows.

```
>>> df['column1'][0] = [1.23, 2.34]
>>> df
     col1
0  [1, 2]
```

For some reason, the DataFrame stored this list as a string instead of a list.

```
>>> df['column1'][0]
'[1.23, 2.34]'
```

I have 2 questions for you.

1. **Why does the DataFrame store a list as a string and is there a way around this behavior?**
2. **If not, then is there a Pythonic way to convert this string into a list?**

---

**Update**

The DataFrame I was using had been saved and loaded from a CSV format. *This format, rather than the DataFrame itself, converted the list from a string to a literal.*

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert string representation of list to list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list)

Answer (score 152, accepted):

As you pointed out, this can commonly happen when saving and loading pandas DataFrames as `.csv` files, which is a text format.

In your case this happened because list objects have a string representation, allowing them to be stored as `.csv` files. Loading the `.csv` will then yield that string representation.

If you want to store the actual objects, you should use `DataFrame.to_pickle()` (note: objects must be picklable!).

To answer your second question, you can convert it back with [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval):

```
>>> from ast import literal_eval
>>> literal_eval('[1.23, 2.34]')
[1.23, 2.34]
```

Answer (score 100):

You can directly use pandas -

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(DF_NAME, converters={'COLUMN_NAME': pd.eval})
```

This will read that column as a it's corresponding dtype in python instead of a string.

UPDATE:

As rightfully pointed out by @ctwardy in comments. It is wiser to use `pd.eval` instead of `eval` to avoid unintended regex related consequences. Details - https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#minimizing-the-security-issues-of-eval

Comment: Just be sure you are using pandas.eval and not builtin eval.  Builtin eval will happily delete all your files if the right expression is in your csv file.  

See  https://realpython.com/python-eval-function/#minimizing-the-security-issues-of-eval.

Comment: @markroxor - Update: `ast.literal_eval` was 15x faster, and looking more it seems `pd.eval` can fall back to Python eval.

Comment: It's good - `pd.eval` has a `python` engine but that's still limited syntax. It refuses to parse `__import__` and even `sum`. (`literal_eval` does seem faster for this use case.)

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` has the benefit of being able to convert also more complex objects (e.g. list of dicts) where `pd.eval` fails.

Answer (score 37):

- Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to safely evaluate a string containing a Python literal or [container datatype](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html).

  - It's part of the standard library
  - [Using python's eval() vs. ast.literal_eval()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15197673/using-pythons-eval-vs-ast-literal-eval/15197698#15197698) explains why `literal_eval` is safer than using `eval`.
  - Examples:

    - `literal_eval("[1.23, 2.34]")` works
    - `literal_eval("['KB4523205','KB4519569','KB4503308']")` works

      - Other answers mention [`pd.eval`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.eval.html), but its usage is limited; it results in `ValueError: NumExpr 2 does not support Unicode as a dtype.` for this simple example.
    - `literal_eval("[KB4523205, KB4519569, KB4503308]")` doesn't work (no quotes around the `str` values)

      - See [pandas - convert string into list of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45758646/pandas-convert-string-into-list-of-strings) for dealing with this representation.
- Convert the column when reading the file, by using the `converters` parameter of [`pandas.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html).

### data in `test.csv`

```py
col1
"[1.23, 2.34]"
"['KB4523205','KB4519569','KB4503308']"
```

### Convert the column when creating the csv

```py
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

# convert the column during import
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'col1': literal_eval})

# display(df)
                                col1
0                       [1.23, 2.34]
1  [KB4523205, KB4519569, KB4503308]

# check type
print(type(df.iloc[0, 0]))
list

print(type(df.iloc[1, 0]))
list
```

### Convert the column of an existing dataframe

```py
df.col1 = df.col1.apply(literal_eval)
```

### `%%timeit`

- `pd.eval` is 28 times slower than `literal_eval`
- Given `test.csv` with 2,820,511 rows of `"[1.23, 2.34]"`

[image]

Answer (score 13):

I just came across this problem and there is a very simple solution ([pandas.eval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.eval.html)).  I'm using pandas 0.20.0.

```
# SETUP
import pandas as pd
import io

csv = io.StringIO(u'''
id  list
A1  [1,2]
A2  [3,4]
A3  [5,6]
''')

df = pd.read_csv(csv, delim_whitespace = True)

# TYPE CHECK <type 'str'>
print type(df.at[0, 'list'])

# MAIN CONVERSION
df['list'] = pd.eval(df['list'])

# TYPE CHECK <type 'list'>
print type(df.at[0, 'list'])
```

Answer (score 3):

1) There is a way around this behavior. Use loc helps here.

```
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['column1'])
>>> df = df.append(pd.Series(data = {'column1':[None]}), ignore_index = True)

   column1
0  [None]

>>> # Add list to index 0 in column1
>>> df.loc[0,'column1'] = [1.23, 2.34]
>>> print(df.loc[0, 'column1'])
[1.23, 2.34]
```

2) Pythonic way to convert this string into a list. (This is probably what you want as the DataFrame you are using had been been saved and loaded from a CSV format, there are a couple solutions for this). This is an addition on pshep123's answer.

```
from ast import literal_eval
import pandas as pd

csv = io.StringIO(u'''
id  list
A1  [1,2]
A2  [3,4]
A3  [5,6]
''')
df = pd.read_csv(csv, delim_whitespace = True)

# Output is a string
df.loc[0, 'list']
'[1,2]'

# Convert entire column to a list
df.loc[:,'list'] = df.loc[:,'list'].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(x))

# Output is a list
df.loc[0, 'list']
[1, 2]
```

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem. When storing a dataframe list column to a CSV file using df.to_csv(), list columns are converted to a string e.g. "[42, 42, 42]" instead of [42, 42, 42]

Alex answer is correct and you can use `literal_eval` to convert the string back to a list. The problem with this approach is that you need to import an additional library and you need to apply or map the function to your dataframe. As easier way is to force Pandas to read the column as a Python object (dtype)

`df["col1"].astype('O')`

The O is used for Python objects including lists. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29245848/what-are-all-the-dtypes-that-pandas-recognizes). Please note that this method fails if you parse empty list strings: "[]"

Alternatively you can also apply a function to your column (this one is for integers):

```
def stringToList(string):
    # input format : "[42, 42, 42]" , note the spaces after the commas, in this case I have a list of integers
    string = string[1:len(string)-1]
    try:
        if len(string) != 0: 
            tempList = string.split(", ")
            newList = list(map(lambda x: int(x), tempList))
        else:
            newList = []
    except:
        newList = [-9999]
    return(newList)

df["col1"] = df["col1"].apply(lambda x: stringToList(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

for reference only... pandas don't convert lists into string. ..

```
In [29]: data2 = [{'a': [1, 5], 'b': 2}, {'a': 5, 'b': 10, 'c': 20}]                                                                                        

In [30]: df = pd.DataFrame(data2)                                                                                                                           

In [31]: df                                                                                                                                                 
Out[31]: 
        a   b   c
0  [1, 5]   2 NaN
1       5  10  20

In [32]: df['a'][0], type(df['a'][0])                                                                                                                       
Out[32]: ([1, 5], list)

In [33]: pd.__version__
Out[33]: '0.12.0'
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple hack I used is to call a lambda function that indexes out the first and last elements (the list brackets in str form) and calls the split method followed by another that replaces the list elements with ints.

```
df['column1'] = df['column1'].apply(lambda x:x[1:-1].split(',')).apply(lambda x:[int(i) for i in x])
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto [Alex's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23112008/11430726) answer. Here is another version which can be used for converting individual items from string to list

```
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

df = pd.read_csv("some_csvfile.csv")

def item_gen(l):
    for i in l:
        yield(i)

for i in item_gen(df["some_column_with_list_item"]):
    print(literal_eval(i))
```