# Grouped boxplot with seaborn from columns of lists

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn, boxplot

I have following data in python panda DataFrame. I would like to have grouped box plot similar to one in https://stanford.edu/~mwaskom/software/seaborn/examples/grouped_boxplot.html

For each id, I would like to have two box plots plotted side by side. How do i achieve this. I tried plotting it with the seaborn package but without any success.

```
id               predicted                              real
1            [10, 10, 10]                      [16, 18, 20]   
2            [12, 12, 15]              [15, 17, 19, 21, 23]
3           [20, 5, 4, 4]                          [29, 32]
4    [25, 25, 25, 24, 21]  [21, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 33]
5        [20, 20, 20, 21]  [21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 31, 32]
6           [8, 3, 3, 14]                          [25, 27]
7  [1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 10]                      [69, 71, 72]
8        [11, 11, 11, 11]              [19, 21, 22, 23, 24]
9            [7, 6, 9, 9]                  [19, 26, 27, 28]
10    [30, 30, 30, 30, 30]                          [38, 39]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice the table structure in the example you are looking at

```
import seaborn as sns

tips = sns.load_dataset("tips")
sns.boxplot(x="day", y="total_bill", hue="sex", data=tips, palette="PRGn")
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
```

[image]

```
tips.head()
```

[image]

---

Our goal is to set your table up like this

#### Setup

```
from StringIO import StringIO
import pandas as pd

text = """id               predicted                              real
1            [10, 10, 10]                      [16, 18, 20]   
2            [12, 12, 15]              [15, 17, 19, 21, 23]
3           [20, 5, 4, 4]                          [29, 32]
4    [25, 25, 25, 24, 21]  [21, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 33]
5        [20, 20, 20, 21]  [21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 31, 32]
6           [8, 3, 3, 14]                          [25, 27]
7  [1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 10]                      [69, 71, 72]
8        [11, 11, 11, 11]              [19, 21, 22, 23, 24]
9            [7, 6, 9, 9]                  [19, 26, 27, 28]
10    [30, 30, 30, 30, 30]                          [38, 39]"""

df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(text), sep='\s{2,}', engine='python', index_col=0)

df = df.stack().str.strip('[]') \
       .str.split(', ').unstack()
df
```

[image]

---

#### Get your table in the correct format

```
df1 = df.stack().apply(pd.Series).stack().astype(int) \
          .rename_axis(['id', 'reality', None]) \
          .rename('value').reset_index(['id', 'reality']) \
          .reset_index(drop=True)

df1.head()
```

[image]

```
sns.boxplot(x='id', y='value', hue='reality', data=df1, palette='PRGn')
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- `print(type(df.loc[0, 'predicted']))` will confirm the values in the column(s) are `list type`. If they are `string type`, then see [Pandas DataFrame stored list as string: How to convert back to list](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63020659/7758804)
- Given [pandas](/questions/tagged/pandas) columns of `list type`, it is easiest to [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) the columns into a long-form, and [`pandas.DataFrame.explode`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) the lists into separate values.
- [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) with [`kind='box'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) creates a `figure-level` plot, while [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39344866/7758804) creates an `axes-level` plot.

  - [Figure-level vs. axes-level functions](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/function_overview.html#figure-level-vs-axes-level-functions)
- **Tested in `python 3.12.0`, `pandas 2.1.2`, `matplotlib 3.8.1`, `seaborn 0.13.0`**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

# convert df to long-form and explode the lists
dfm = df.melt(id_vars='id').explode('value')

# plot figure-level boxplot
g = sns.catplot(kind='box', data=dfm, x='id', y='value', hue='variable', height=5, aspect=2)
```

[image]

#### `df`

```py
data = {'id': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10], 'predicted': [[10, 10, 10], [12, 12, 15], [20, 5, 4, 4], [25, 25, 25, 24, 21], [20, 20, 20, 21], [8, 3, 3, 14], [1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 10], [11, 11, 11, 11], [7, 6, 9, 9], [30, 30, 30, 30, 30]],
        'real': [[16, 18, 20], [15, 17, 19, 21, 23], [29, 32], [21, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 33], [21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 31, 32], [25, 27], [69, 71, 72], [19, 21, 22, 23, 24], [19, 26, 27, 28], [38, 39]]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

   id               predicted                              real
0   1            [10, 10, 10]                      [16, 18, 20]
1   2            [12, 12, 15]              [15, 17, 19, 21, 23]
2   3           [20, 5, 4, 4]                          [29, 32]
3   4    [25, 25, 25, 24, 21]  [21, 24, 25, 26, 28, 29, 30, 33]
4   5        [20, 20, 20, 21]  [21, 22, 24, 26, 28, 30, 31, 32]
5   6           [8, 3, 3, 14]                          [25, 27]
6   7  [1, 4, 4, 4, 5, 6, 10]                      [69, 71, 72]
7   8        [11, 11, 11, 11]              [19, 21, 22, 23, 24]
8   9            [7, 6, 9, 9]                  [19, 26, 27, 28]
9  10    [30, 30, 30, 30, 30]                          [38, 39]
```

#### `dfm`

```
    id   variable value
0    1  predicted    10
0    1  predicted    10
0    1  predicted    10
1    2  predicted    12
1    2  predicted    12
1    2  predicted    15
2    3  predicted    20
2    3  predicted     5
2    3  predicted     4
2    3  predicted     4
3    4  predicted    25
3    4  predicted    25
3    4  predicted    25
3    4  predicted    24
3    4  predicted    21
4    5  predicted    20
4    5  predicted    20
4    5  predicted    20
4    5  predicted    21
5    6  predicted     8
5    6  predicted     3
5    6  predicted     3
5    6  predicted    14
6    7  predicted     1
6    7  predicted     4
6    7  predicted     4
6    7  predicted     4
6    7  predicted     5
6    7  predicted     6
6    7  predicted    10
7    8  predicted    11
7    8  predicted    11
7    8  predicted    11
7    8  predicted    11
8    9  predicted     7
8    9  predicted     6
8    9  predicted     9
8    9  predicted     9
9   10  predicted    30
9   10  predicted    30
9   10  predicted    30
9   10  predicted    30
9   10  predicted    30
10   1       real    16
10   1       real    18
10   1       real    20
11   2       real    15
11   2       real    17
11   2       real    19
11   2       real    21
11   2       real    23
12   3       real    29
12   3       real    32
13   4       real    21
13   4       real    24
13   4       real    25
13   4       real    26
13   4       real    28
13   4       real    29
13   4       real    30
13   4       real    33
14   5       real    21
14   5       real    22
14   5       real    24
14   5       real    26
14   5       real    28
14   5       real    30
14   5       real    31
14   5       real    32
15   6       real    25
15   6       real    27
16   7       real    69
16   7       real    71
16   7       real    72
17   8       real    19
17   8       real    21
17   8       real    22
17   8       real    23
17   8       real    24
18   9       real    19
18   9       real    26
18   9       real    27
18   9       real    28
19  10       real    38
19  10       real    39
```