# Plotting box plots of two columns side by side in seaborn

Tags: python, seaborn

I would like to plot two columns of a pandas dataframe as side by side box plots by category. This is not the same as the question presented in here: [Grouped boxplot with seaborn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39344167/grouped-boxplot-with-seaborn) where the two columns have lists inside them. The solution there did not work for me.

## MWE

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
[2, 4, "A"],
[4, 5, "C"],
[5, 4, "B"],
[10, 4.2, "A"],
[9, 3, "B"],
[3, 3, "C"]
], columns=['data1', 'data2', 'Categories'])

#Plotting by seaborn
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1, 1)
sns.boxplot(data=df,x="Categories",y='data1',ax=axs)
fig.show()
plt.waitforbuttonpress()
plt.close(fig)
```

---

The code above generates:
[image]

Replacing "data1" with "data2" in the boxplot line would give:
[image]

What I want is something like this:
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to `melt` (convert to long format) the `DataFrame` first:

```
data = df.melt(id_vars=['Categories'], var_name='dataset', value_name='values')
print(data)
```

Prints:

```
   Categories dataset  values
0           A   data1     2.0
1           A   data2     4.0
2           C   data1     4.0
3           C   data2     5.0
4           B   data1     5.0
5           B   data2     4.0
6           A   data1    10.0
7           A   data2     4.2
8           B   data1     9.0
9           B   data2     3.0
10          C   data1     3.0
11          C   data2     3.0
```

Now you just have to use `dataset` as the hue. Since the plot is quite busy I moved the legend outside it.

```
sns.boxplot(data=data, x='Categories', y='values', hue='dataset')
plt.legend(title='dataset', loc='upper left', bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1))
```

[image]

**Edit by OP**:

I implemented this in a function such that it makes the plot with as many columns as desired in an ax and returns it.

```
def box_plot_columns(df,categories_column,list_of_columns,legend_title,y_axis_title,**boxplotkwargs):
    columns = [categories_column] + list_of_columns
    newdf = df[columns].copy()
    data = newdf.melt(id_vars=[categories_column], var_name=legend_title, value_name=y_axis_title)
    return sns.boxplot(data=data, x=categories_column, y=y_axis_title, hue=legend_title, **boxplotkwargs)
```

Usage Example:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
ax = box_plot_columns(Data,"Categories",["data1","data2"],"dataset","values",ax=ax)
ax.set_title("My Plot")
plt.show()
```

Comment: It is unfortunate that there isn't a way of doing it without having to restructure the data. Thanks!

Comment: @Miguel There was an easier way after all. `factorplot` does a better job with the legend but I prefer an axes-level plot for this and the legend can be moved.

Answer (score 1):

Try This  :

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
[2, 4, "A"],
[4, 5, "C"],
[5, 4, "B"],

[10, 4.2, "A"],
[9, 3, "B"],
[3, 3, "C"]
], columns=['data1', 'data2', 'Categories'])

#Plotting by seaborn
df_c = pd.melt(df, "Categories", var_name="data1", value_name="data2")
sns.factorplot("Categories",hue="data1", y="data2", data=df_c, kind="box")
```