# How to count a number of occurrences in Data Frame?

Tags: python, python-2.7, sorting, dataframe, find-occurrences

Need help.
I have Pandas DataFrame like:

```
Shown ID                                       Bought ID
59,60,61,62,60,63,64,65,66,61,67,68,67         67,60,63
63,64,63,64,63,65,66                           0
87,63,84,63,86                                 86
```

I need to find the number of occurrences of each number of each "Show ID" row in whole "Show ID" column.

So the expected result for "Shown ID" column is:

```
    [[('59', 1), ('60', 2), ('61', 2), ('62', 1), ('63', 6),
      ('64', 3), ('65', 2), ('66', 2), ('67', 2), ('68', 1)],
     [('63', 6), ('64', 3), ('65', 2), ('66', 2)],
     [('87', 1), ('63', 6), ('84', 1), ('86', 1)]]
```

How to do that?

Then I need to create a list of lists with sorted values of each row of "Shown ID" column (each list of result list of lists above).

So summary result must be:

```
[['63', '64', '60', '61', '65', '66', '67', '68', '59', '62'],
 ['63', '64', '65', '66'],
 ['63', '87', '84', '86']]
```

How Can I do that?
If the numbers have the same frequency of occurrences, it needs to sort in ascending appearing in list (the earlier appeared in row, the more priority)

Comment: is my answer what you are looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can get what you are looking for:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import Counter


data = [{'c_id' : [59,60,61,62,60,63,64,65,66,61,67,68,67]},
{'c_id' : [63,64,63,64,63,65,66]},
{'c_id' : [87,63,84,63,86]}]

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['c_id'].apply(lambda val: [key for key,val in Counter(val).most_common()])
```

output:

```
0    [67, 60, 61, 64, 65, 66, 68, 59, 62, 63]
1                            [63, 64, 65, 66]
2                            [63, 84, 86, 87]
```

Values which have the same count might come in any order.

If you want to make column level counter then you can do it like this:

```
all_cids = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    all_cids.extend(row['c_id'])

import operator
counter_obj = Counter(all_cids)

def get_ordered_values(values):
    new_values = []
    covered_valeus = set()
    for val in values:
        if val in covered_valeus:
            continue
        covered_valeus.add(val)
        new_values.append((val, counter_obj[val]))    
    new_values.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
    return [key for key, val in new_values]

df['c_id'].apply(lambda values: get_ordered_values(values))
```

output

```
0    [63, 64, 60, 61, 65, 66, 67, 59, 62, 68]
1                            [63, 64, 65, 66]
2                            [63, 84, 86, 87]
```

Comment: Thanks, but correct result is:                                                                  ['63', '64', '60', '61', '65', '66', '67', '68', '59', '62'],
['63', '64', '65', '66'],
['63', '87', '84', '86'] It's a different order in your version

Comment: @AlexSavin do you want it sorted in reverse?? Please check your data first. first row has 63 count as 1. Do you want to keep a Global count on the entire column and sort by that ??

Comment: You right, In first row 63 count as 1, but in all rows of "Shown ID" column 63 occurred 6 times. So this number the most frequently occured in column.

Comment: @AlexSavin So you need a global count across the column. We can do that. Give me sometime.

Comment: @AlexSavin added another example for column level counter. Please check and let me know if this is what you want. Thanks

Comment: Your output is [63, 64, 65, 66, 67, 60, 61, 68, 59, 62], but correct output must be ['63', '64', '60', '61', '65', '66', '67', '68', '59', '62'] At first, elements sorted in descending order of occurrences. If some elements have the same number of occurances they shouldn't be sorted and they should follows each other with original order.

Comment: @AlexSavin have made the change as you were expecting. please check.

Comment: Correct output!) But there is some problem. Your code works correct. But my data some different. I import data from .txt file in dataframe `data = pd.read_csv('file.txt', sep = ';', names = ['Shown_ID', 'Bought_ID'])`. The separator divides data to two columns - Shown_ID and Bought_ID. In file every row looks like `59,60,61,62,60,63,64,65,66,61,67,68,67;67,60,63` And the rows isn't numbers, but it is strings. So type of data['Shown'] is 'pandas.core.series.Series'. I don't know how convert it to integers.

Comment: This should solve that problem http://stackoverflow.com/a/23112008/3027854

Answer (score 1):

If i understand it completely , you want to find number of occurrences but not list of indexes where specific data is found. I can imagine several ways of doing this:

1. way:, count the data.

If your data type is not the multidimensional list, then you can simple use count function in list object.

```
# in python3 you would need list(range(3)) etc to test this example
someList = range(3)+range(2)+range(1)

sortedElements = sorted(set(someList)) #> looses duplicates of elements, somelist must be hash-able

for x in sortedElements:
    # list.count(somelist,element) is usable for python2.7 and python3.5
    # tested myself on py interpreter, i can not say for IronPython and/or Rhino enviorment
    print( x, someList.count(x) ) # and there you will have element, and number of occurrences
```

2. Returning indexes of duplications:

   ```
   #somelist same as before
   #sortedElements same as before
   for x in sortedElements:
         lIndexes = [ someList.index(elem) for elem in sortedElements if elem == x] 
         print(lIndexes)
   ```
3. Multidimensional list:

As i see it, you must first dump the whole list into 1 list or , do **steps 1 or 2** on each child list of multidimensional list depending on your need.
Of course there is several way to transverse multidimensional list, you can `map` or `filter` or `reduce` or `pass them as *arguments` etc ( there are too many ways to transverse multi list for me to count, you can find most of the methods on this website ) but the method of your choosing is very tightly connected to your example. Without further explanation i would not dare to consult you since it could do more damage and good.

Hope this helps.