# Converting list of strings in pandas column into string

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df with a column like this:

```
                       words
1                     ['me']
2                   ['they']
4         ['it', 'we', 'it']
5                         []
6         ['we', 'we', 'it']
```

I want it to look like this:

```
                     words
1                     'me'
2                   'they'
4               'it we it'
5                       ''          
6               'we we it'
```

I have tried both these options, but they both yield in a result identical to the original series.

```
def join_words(df):
    words_string = ''.join(df.words)
    return words_string

master_df['words_string'] = master_df.apply(join_words, axis=1)
```

and...

```
master_df['words_String'] = master_df.words.str.join(' ')
```

Both these result in the original df. What am I doing wrong?

#### Edit

Using `master_df['words_string'] = master_df['words'].apply(' '.join)`, I got:

```
1                                     [ ' m e ' ]
2                                 [ ' t h e y ' ]
4             [ ' i t ' ,   ' w e ' ,   ' i t ' ]
5                                             [ ]
6             [ ' w e ' ,   ' w e ' ,   ' i t ' ]
```

Comment: ummm may be it is not an actual list? else `master_df.words.str.join(' ')` should work, check `ast.literal_eval` if they are just the string repr of a list , its better to include `df.head().to_dict()` in your question too

Comment: `df['words'].apply(literal_eval).agg(' '.join)` if it's a list not a string

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame stored list as string: How to convert back to list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111990/pandas-dataframe-stored-list-as-string-how-to-convert-back-to-list)

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894269/convert-string-representation-of-list-to-list.

Comment: Please provide a proper [mcve], especially since we discovered that the contents of your Series are **strings, not lists** as your post currently implies. The formatting in your post needs some editing, but I am unable to do so as we're lacking some accessible and easy to use examples of your data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Edit:

As your edit shows, it seems the rows are not actually `lists` but `strings` interpreted as lists. We can use `eval` to ensure the format is of type `list` so as to later perform the `join`. It seems your sample data is the following:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,3,4],
                   'words':["['me']","['they']","['it','we','it']","[]","['we','we','it']"]})
```

How about this? Using `apply` with a lambda function which uses `' '.join()` for each row (list):

```
df['words'] = df['words'].apply(eval).apply(' '.join)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   index     words
0      0        me
1      1      they
2      2  it we it
3      3          
4      4  we we it
```

Comment: Why not `apply(' '.join)`?

Comment: You are right! For a reason I thought it'd be safer to use lambda with lists. Thanks, edited

Comment: That didn't work, I got the result seen in the edit above

Comment: @connor449 looks like your cells are `string`, not `list` type.

Comment: Why use `eval()` instead of `ast.literal_eval()` ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally I'd advise against `eval`. Here's another approach when the elements are `string` not `list`:

```
words.str.extractall("'(\w*)'").groupby(level=0)[0].agg(' '.join)
```

Output:

```
1          me
2        they
4    it we it
6    we we it
Name: 0, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Another idea is using the [DataFrame.explode](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.explode.html) (since version 0.25.0) and the groupby/aggregate methods.

```
import pandas as pd

# create a list of list of strings
values = [
    ['me'],
    ['they'],
    ['it', 'we', 'it'],
    [],
    ['we', 'we', 'it']
]

# convert to a data frame
df = pd.DataFrame({'words': values})

# explode the cells (with lists) into separate rows having the same index
df2 = df.explode('words')
df2
```

This creates a table in the long-format giving the following output:

```
  words
0    me
1  they
2    it
2    we
2    it
3   nan
4    we
4    we
4    it
```

Now the long-format needs to be joined / aggregated:

```
# make sure the dtype is string
df2['words'] = df2['words'].astype(str)

# group by the index aggregating all values to a single string
df2.groupby(level=0).agg(' '.join)
```

giving the output:

```
      words
0        me
1      they
2  it we it
3       nan
4  we we it
```