# How to Delist a dataframe row whose value is a list

Tags: python, pandas

I want to convert the below data frame into space-separated in python.
Like:

```
0  ['raj', 'kumar']
1  ['kill', 'bill']
```

To

```
0  raj kumar
1  kill bill
```

Comment: Does [Converting list of strings in pandas column into string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60327204/converting-list-of-strings-in-pandas-column-into-string) answer your question?

Comment: Also, check the docs, there's a method: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.join.html

Comment: Somewhat related: [Column of lists, convert list to string as a new column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45306988/column-of-lists-convert-list-to-string-as-a-new-column)

Comment: try using reduce and join to create a string of the list

Comment: @wwii That seems to be a different problem. OP's data there turned out to be strings that look like lists, not actually lists.

Answer (score -1):

try using reduce for each row in the dataframe

```
data=[{'value': ['raj', 'kumar']},
{'value':  ['kill', 'bill']}]
df=pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
def concatWords(lst):
    return functools.reduce(lambda x,y: x+" "+y,lst)
df["value"]=df["value"].apply(concatWords)
print(df)
```

output:

```
value
0  raj kumar
1  kill bill
```