# How do I read in a list of list of floats in a single column from an excel sheet in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a structure like the following in .xlsx format (written with pandas .to_xlsx() function)

```html
|---------------------|------------------|
|      A              |     B            |
|---------------------|------------------|
| [[2 3] [3 4] [4 5]] |         34       |
|---------------------|------------------|
```

[image]

When I read this using `df = pd.read_xlsx()`, the `df['A']` is a string - `'[[2 3]\n[3 4]\n[4 5]]'`

Is there a way to read it as a list of list of int or float?

Comment: I think [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111990/pandas-dataframe-stored-list-as-string-how-to-convert-back-to-list/23112008) and it's answers might be helpful to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to convert string into list:

```
cell = eval('[[2 3]\n[3 4]\n[4 5]]'.replace('\n',' ').replace(' ',','))
```

result:

```
[[2, 3], [3, 4], [4, 5]]
```

Preferred method is to use `literal_eval` from `ast`:

```
from ast import literal_eval
cell = literal_eval('[[2 3]\n[3 4]\n[4 5]]'.replace('\n',' ').replace(' ',','))
```

Result is the same as above, but method is better than `eval`, because it safely evaluates strings containing values from untrusted sources without the need to parse the values by hand.

Comment: `ast.literal_eval` is safer: `ast.literal_eval('[[2 3]\n[3 4]\n[4 5]]'.replace('\n',' ').replace(' ',','))`