# Read a list from a csv row 'as a list' in python using DictReader

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

My CSV file looks like this:

```
    id,name,list
    1,Beans,[1,2,3]
    2,Spam,[5,6,7]
    5,Spam,[7,8,9]
```

When I try to read the last column using the following code:

```
with open('some.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
     reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
     for row in reader:
         print(row["list"])
```

the  output i get is:

```
[1
[5
[7
```

Apparently, it separates the list at the first ','. However i want it to read the whole list as one column. So my expected output is:

```
[1,2,3]
[5,6,7]
[7,8,9]
```

I plan to store each of these in variables so they can be used as I'd use a normal list to iterate over it or perform other tasks.

How do i achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The issue is the CSV is not properly formatted with double quotes around the lists

  - Fix the CSV file, by wrapping the `lists` column in double quotes

    - `list` is a python data type, so it should never be used as a variable name.
- Use this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63020659) for `pandas`

  - [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to evaluate the strings back into lists

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval

# fix the csv file by wrapping the list with quotes
with open('test.csv', 'r+', newline='') as f:
    rows = [s.replace(',[', ',"[').replace(']', ']"').strip() for s in f.readlines()]
    f.seek(0)
    f.truncate()
    f.writelines(s + '\n' for s in rows)


# read the csv and evaluate the list column as lists
df = pd.read_csv('test.csv', converters={'lists': literal_eval})

# display(df)
   id   name      lists
0   1  Beans  [1, 2, 3]
1   2   Spam  [5, 6, 7]
2   5   Spam  [7, 8, 9]
3   6  Steak         []

print(type(df.loc[0, 'lists']))
[out]:
list
```

### `with open`

```
# converts
id,name,lists
1,Beans,[1,2,3]
2,Spam,[5,6,7]
5,Spam,[7,8,9]
6,Steak,[]

# into
id,name,lists
1,Beans,"[1,2,3]"
2,Spam,"[5,6,7]"
5,Spam,"[7,8,9]"
6,Steak,"[]"
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to change the input file you can still work with it using the following code to handle the list column -

```
with open('test.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    stringVal = ","
    for row in reader:
        newList = row['list'] + "," + stringVal.join(row[None])
        print(newList)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem has to do with your csv file. If that is what the actual file looks like, then it will do as you say it does. Wrap the list in double quotes like this:

```
    id,name,list
    1,Beans,"[1,2,3]"
    2,Spam,"[5,6,7]"
    5,Spam,"[7,8,9]"
```

Comment: For future reference, I would use `csv.DictWriter` or `pandas` to write to csv next time - it will take care of proper conversions for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can quote your csv file like this:

```
"id","name","list"
"1","Beans","[1,2,3]"
"2","Spam","[5,6,7]"
"5","Spam","[7,8,9]"
```

Then you can read it using `csv` module with an optional argument `quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL`.
After this you can convert these "string lists" to regular lists. e.x. if these "string lists" are numeric only then you can filter the results and then cast it to ints. Here is code:

```
import csv

with open('test.csv', 'r') as fh:
    data = list(csv.reader(fh, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL))
    for i in range(1, 4):
      data[i][2] = list(filter(lambda c: str.isnumeric(c), data[i][2]))
      data[i][2] = list(map(lambda c: int(c), data[i][2]))
    print(*data, sep='\n')
```

And the results:

```
['id', 'name', 'list']
['1', 'Beans', [1, 2, 3]]
['2', 'Spam', [5, 6, 7]]
['5', 'Spam', [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: This is not what the OP said the CSV file looks like.