# Convert pandas column to individual lists

Tags: python, pandas, string, list

I have a df with a column like this:

```
col1
["12233","2344","3454"]
["233","43234","3455"]
["1234","2534","34655"]
```

However, when i run this:

```
print(df1.applymap(type))
```

Python tells me the column is not in a list; i get this:

```
          parent       col1       func_results
0  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'list'>
1  <class 'str'>  <class 'str'>  <class 'list'>
```

How do i convert each row/cell in 'col1' to a list?

Comment: ``from ast import literal_eval; df.col1.apply(literal_eval)`` ?

Comment: Please remember to use the [tag:pandas] tag when asking about Pandas.

Comment: @sushanth that worked! ugh, thanks so much.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas DataFrame stored list as string: How to convert back to list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111990/pandas-dataframe-stored-list-as-string-how-to-convert-back-to-list)