# How to convert string entries within a dataset to float?

Tags: pandas, string, dataframe, numeric

I am trying to convert string to float in a dataset. The dataset consists of several columns where one of the columns contains entries:

| col1 | col2 |
| --- | --- |
| x | [1.1, 1.2, 1.3 ... |

When I use `pd.to_numeric` I get the following error:
Unable to parse string "[1.1, 1.2........]" at position 0.

**This is a simplified version of my code, where the numbers resemble this 2.1874960973678963

Comment: What output do you expect? A list of floats?

Comment: Something like [Pandas DataFrame stored list as string: How to convert back to list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23111990/15497888) or [How can I save DataFrame as list and not as string](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64183163/15497888) ?

Comment: @mozway Yes, I am using a program that reads the csv file and it says that it couldn't convert string to float.

Comment: @HenryEcker I tried those solutions, but its no use.

Comment: @user16470918 I provided an alternative in case you have lists of strings (I briefly saw your comment, then it disappeared, so I don't know if it's still valid)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### elements are strings

Assuming you want to convert a string representation of a list of floats (`"[1.1, 1.2, 1.3]"`) to a list of floats:

input:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1':['x'], 'col2':'[1.1, 1.2, 1.3]'})
```

processing:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda s: list(map(float, s.strip('[]').split(', '))))
```

edit: check the [link provided by @Henry Ecker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64183163/15497888), there is a nice solution with `ast.literal_eval`

```
import ast
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(ast.literal_eval)
```

#### elements are lists of strings

If your elements are already lists of strings (`['1.1', '1.2', '1.3']`), use:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: [float(i) for i in x])
```

or:

```
df['col2'] = df['col2'].apply(lambda x: list(map(float, x)))
```