# How to read a csv with a malformed column of lists and plot the values

Tags: python, pandas, csv, matplotlib, plot

I have a file csv with the following columns

```
Customer List_Items
J.B.      [13,2,3,4,42,12]
F.C.      [1,44,51,24,12,53]
D.S.      NA 
B.V.      *
F.R.      [1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

I have max six items. The elements in the lists above are the frequency. The elements above are strings, not lists, since the file csv was created manually outside python coding.
I would like to plot a multiline charts where, on the y-axis I have the frequency and on the x-axis the labels 1,2,3,4,5,6.
To exclude values not in scope I could filter out NA and *. But I do not know how to plot lists in a multiline plot. Should I expand the lists in separate columns?

For example:
J.B. would be represented by a line with

```
x-axis y-axis
1      13
2      2
3      3
4      4
5      42
6      12
```

Similarly for the other customers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- A column can be converted from strings back to lists using:

  - `df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\\s+', index_col=[0], converters={'List_Items': literal_eval})` - **This will not work for this OP**

    - See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63020659/7758804) for [Pandas DataFrame stored list as string: How to convert back to list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23111990/7758804)
  - **But only if the column does not have malformed values (e.g. `'nan'`, `'*'`)**
- In this case there needs to be a function, which can handle errors with `try-except`
- `df.T.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)` works to separate the values in each `list` to individual rows.

  - This only works if each `list` is the same length, as shown in the example.
  - If the lists have different lengths, use the following line instead:

    - `df = pd.concat([df.T[col].explode().reset_index(drop=True) for col in df.T.columns], axis=1)`
- Plot the dataframe with [`pandas.DataFrame.plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html).

### Imports and Load DataFrame

```py
import pandas as pd
from ast import literal_eval  # convert string back to list
import numpy as np

# read the file
df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep='\\s+', index_col=[0])

# display(df)
                  List_Items
Customer                    
J.B.        [13,2,3,4,42,12]  ← this is a string
F.C.      [1,44,51,24,12,53]
D.S.                     NaN
B.V.                       *
F.R.           [1,0,0,0,0,0]
```

### Function

```py
# create a function with error handling to convert the column back to lists
def test(row):
    try:
        row = literal_eval(row)  # convert the string to a list
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
        row = np.nan  # malformed rows are returned as NaN
    return row
```

### Fix Data and Plot

```py
# apply the function to the row
df.List_Items = df.List_Items.apply(lambda row: test(row))

# drop nan
df = df.dropna()

# display(df)
                       List_Items
Customer                         
J.B.        [13, 2, 3, 4, 42, 12]  ← this is a list
F.C.      [1, 44, 51, 24, 12, 53]
F.R.           [1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]

# transpose the dataframe and explode the list values to separate rows
df = df.T.apply(pd.Series.explode).reset_index(drop=True)

# display(df)
Customer J.B. F.C. F.R.
0          13    1    1
1           2   44    0
2           3   51    0
3           4   24    0
4          42   12    0
5          12   53    0

# plot
ax = df.plot()
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and for your well-explained answer. It makes sense to me and it works fine. Thanks for your time and help Trenton

Comment: @LdM you're welcome. I'm glad this works for you.