# tf.int32 Being interpreted as tf.string when constructing a tensorflow dataset

Tags: python, pandas, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I have a Pandas dataframe whose data I intend to export to a Tensorflow dataset. This dataframe has 4 columns, of which 2 of them are lists of strings and the remaining two are lists of integers. For the time being, the most important columns are `input_ids` and `attention_mask`, which constitute the input data of the model.

```
train_input_ids = train_df["input_ids"].values.tolist()
train_attention_mask = train_df["attention_mask"].values.tolist()
```

As the `head()` method shows, these columns store lists of ints. `print(train_df["input_ids"].head(3))` returns the following:

```
0    [101, 24918, 7821, 5983, 46106, 21905, 10789...
1    [101, 33198, 10173, 14657, 25287, 55610, 10789...
2    [101, 10109, 19217, 34768, 16294, 17953, 51733...
Name: input_ids, dtype: object
```

One of the other columns, `codes`, stores a list of strings containing codes to be one-hot encoded:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
y_train = label_encoder.fit_transform(train_df["codes"].values)
```

I created the dataset as follows:

```
    train_dataset = (
    tf.data.Dataset
    .from_tensor_slices(((  tf.convert_to_tensor(train_input_ids), tf.convert_to_tensor(train_attention_mask)), y_train))
    .repeat()
    .shuffle(2048)
    .batch(BATCH_SIZE)
    .prefetch(BATCH_SIZE * 2)
    )
```

However, after trying to build the dataset from tensor slices and printing the resulting datasets, I've found that both `train_input_ids`and `train_attention_mask` are interpreted as `tf.string`:

```
<PrefetchDataset shapes: (((None,), (None,)), (None,)), types: ((tf.string, tf.string), tf.int64)>
```

As far as I know, they should be inferred as `types: ((tf.int32, tf.int32)` because the dataframe contains lists of ints as opposed to lists of strings (it is also the way the model accepts the inputs in the input layers definition). What am I missing?

Comment: Can you show an example of what `train_df["codes"].values` looks like?

Comment: can you post some reproducible code with example values?

Comment: Thanks to the hint provided by @AloneTogether, I managed to guess what was going on. After deserialising the dataframe, instead of returning the lists (e.g. `[101, 24918, 7821, 5983, 46106, etc.]`), a string representation of such lists between quotes was being returned (e.g. `"[101, 24918, 7821, 5983, 46106, etc.]"`). Consequently, after doing some further investigation I managed to come up with a solution, which I've written in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually discovered that at the end of the day I was having an issue very similar to the one described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111990/pandas-dataframe-stored-list-as-string-how-to-convert-back-to-list). Therefore, since all of the columns of this dataframe store lists, I adapted one of the proposed solutions by defining a function which is to be called after retrieving the dataframe from its corresponding .tsv file:

```
from ast import literal_eval

def _remove_extra_quotes(df):
    def apply_lambda(column):
        df[column] = df[column].apply(lambda x: literal_eval(str(x)))
        return
    for column_name in df:
        apply_lambda(column_name)
    return df
```