# Converting every other csv file column from python list to value

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, csv

I have several large csv filess each 100 columns and 800k rows. Starting from the first column, every other column has cells that are like python list, for example: in cell A2, I have [1000], in cell A3: I have [2300], and so forth. Column 2 is fine and are numbers, but columns 1, 3, 5, 7, etc, ...99 are similar to the column 1, their values are inside list. Is there an efficient way to remove the sign of the list [] from those columns and make their cells like normal numbers?

```
    files_directory: r":D\my_files"
    dir_files =os.listdir(r"D:\my_files")

    for file in dir_files:
        edited_csv = pd.read_csv("%s\%s"%(files_directory, file))

        for column in list(edited_csv.columns):
           if (column % 2) != 0:
              edited_csv[column] = ?
```

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23111990/pandas-dataframe-stored-list-as-string-how-to-convert-back-to-list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header=None)
df.columns = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
for x in df.columns[::2]:
    df[x] = df[x].apply(lambda x: float(x[1:-1]))
print(df)
```

Answer (score 0):

When reading the cells, for example `column_1[3]`, which in this case is `[4554.8433]`, python will read them as arrays. To read the numerical value inside the array, simply read the values like so:

```
value = column_1[3]
print(value[0]) #prints 4554.8433 instead of [4554.8433]
```

Comment: Is there any automated way to convert all these odd columns (1, 3, 5, etc..) into regular number cells and have the csv file saved??